# How to check if a list of object contains an object with a specified properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a list of duplicates object:

```
var duplicates = workspace.Maps.GroupBy(m => m.sFolder).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

I want an `if` statement to check if the list contains an object with a particular properties:

```
if (duplicates.Contains(myObject.sFolder)) // "myObject.sFolder" raise an error (of course)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *i can't do that like this* exactly?

Comment: Not sure on whats being compared here but something like this?

if (duplicates.Any(x => x.sFolder == myObject.sFolder)) // But i can't do that like this...
{
    // Do stuff
}

Comment: Why not use a for loop and break once you find the duplicate if you expect one match at max

Comment: @S.Akbari Sorry i've updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check by this way

```
if (duplicates.Any(a => a.sFolder == myObject.sFolder))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on whats being compared here but something like this?

```
if (duplicates.Any(x => x.sFolder == myObject.sFolder)) 
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need the duplicate object for further inspection try

```
var duplicate = duplicates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.sFolder == myObject.sFolder);

if(duplicate != null)
{
    // Further check duplicate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach`

```
  foreach (var item in duplicates)
            {
                if (item.sFolder == myObject.sFolder )
                {
                    // Do stuff
                    break;
                }
            }
```